# How do you change the title of a field collection edit form?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

Here is an example edit URL for a field collection I have field-photo-block:

> /field-collection/field-photo-block/65/edit

The title of this page is being set to the title of the field collection. How do I change it to something descriptive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a custom module (or even theme), you can add this function. Replace `YOURMODULE` with the name of your module or theme.

```
<?php
function YOURMODULE_form_field_collection_item_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_set_title(t('Your title'));
}
```